# SQL Server using regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, try-catch, public

I am using the below query to search some text in a sentence

```
declare @a nvarchar(100)
set @a=N'%[ /\\@\&\*()\-\+\|\>?,\":;／、・￥—＆＊（－》＞？，；“”〉\- ][public]'

declare @b nvarchar(50)

set @b='public property'

select @b where @b like '%' +@a+'%'
```

1. The problem is that I just want to fetch special character or the exact keyword from the sentence which is stored in `@b`.
   Example: I want `public` or `&public` not `republic`
2. We cannot change the logic in like statement.
3. The only change we can do is in the variable `@a`

Answer (score 0):

the `[public]` matches one character which is eiter p, u, b, l, i or c. so first you need to fix that to `public`.

as for the character before that i think excluding things you do not want to match is easier in this case. i suggest:

```
declare @a nvarchar(100)
set @a=N'[^a-zA-Z]public'

declare @b nvarchar(50)

set @b=' public property'

select @b where @b like '%' +@a+'%'
```

instead, excluding all letters from being before `public`. however there will be problems when public is the first item in your `@b` as you are trying to match something that is not a letter before it. making that match optional will result in the `%` from your select matching letters as well. i see no way of getting around that without changing the select.